# Understanding `apply` and `unapply` with Singleton Type

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.singleton._

case class Foo(a: String, one: Witness.`1`.T)
```

Why do `Foo.apply _` and `Foo.unapply _` have different signatures, namely the `Int(1)` versus `Int`, respectively?

```
scala> Foo.apply _
res5: (String, Int(1)) => Foo = <function2>

scala> Foo.unapply _
res6: Foo => Option[(String, Int)] = <function1>
```

Comment: For what is worth, in scala 2.12.2 I get `(String, 1) => Foo` and `Foo => Option[(String, 1)]`, which is probably what you'd expect. In scala 2.11.11 I get `(String, 1) => Foo` and `Foo => Option[(String, Int)]`, and finally in scala 2.10.6 I get `(String, Int(1))` and `Foo => Option[(String, Int)]` (just like you).

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter though, because in 2.10.6 this still works: ``val a: Witness.`2`.T = Foo("a",1) match { case Foo(_,one) => one + 1; case _ => 2 }``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, in `scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers` (compiler code), `apply` *used* to be generated by `completerOf` *and* `caseApplyMethodCompleter`, while `unapply` *used* to come from just `completerOf`. This and probably other factors, likely some subtle bugs, causes `unapply` to lose type information. [This change](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5816) refactors the code a bit and results in *both* methods going through the new `applyUnapplyMethodCompleter`, which fixes it. Since there doesn't appear to be any ticket on the issue, the true cause will take some extra digging. It's probably safe to assume that this wasn't intended behavior.